# What's the easiest way to add hotkeys to a webpage?

Tags: hotkeys

I want to add some hotkeys to my webpage, such as using j/k as page up/down, as this web page did: http://www.theatlantic.com/infocus/2011/07/tour-de-france-2011---part-1/100105/

What's the easiest/cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 //could be any key you want ) {
     // do what you want
   }
});
```

This is using the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) library (which I think you should use if possible :) )